# selenium web driver : Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Well not to mention that I'm new on using the selenium web driver, I'm trying to automatize a mailbox so I can log myself in and to send a message, the thing is that I download the firebug plugin for Mozilla, that is the browser I'm currently working with, when I'm trying to find the element for the log in and the password everything goes well, because I do it by their name.

```
input class="_nb-input-controller" type="text" **name="login"** autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" value=""

input class="_nb-input-controller" type="password" **name="passwd"** value=""
```

but as soon as im at the mailbox entry the identificator changes it, i go to compose link and this is the code that shows up:

```
a class="b-toolbar__item b-toolbar__item_compose js-toolbar-item-compose daria-action" title="Compose (w, c)" href="#compose" data-action="compose.go" data-params="toolbar=1&toolbar.button=compose"
```

Since I don't find any method that could help on this, a friend came and told me about the xpath which was:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[2]
```

by doing this selenium did find the element and I could click on the icon,

but again.. when I'm trying to get into the "TO" prompt so I can write inside
it is not finding the element, not by xpath, or anything is there a way or formula to get elements or translate them into a way that selenium can find them???

Comment: Firstly, if  class="b-toolbar__item b-toolbar__item_compose js-toolbar-item-compose is unique, you can use. //a[@class'your class name'] second issur, which element you cannot access? TO field?

Comment: You can try to install selenium IDE in your browser, use it to record your interactions and from the script it generates you can pick what identifiers it used to capture your element. Other than that, I would recommend using the web developer tools in FireFox to get the elements you are interested in. In my FireFox it is tools->web developer->inspector. This allows to view the elements and their xpaths, classes, etc. even if it was built dynamically. As for your specific TO field, I have no idea since I dont have your app.

Answer (score 0):

Having locators such as :

`/html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/a[2]`

is generally a bad idea. If you want to build a stable test I would suggest you stay away from such.

Now I see you have attributes like `@name` and `@class`. XPath is provides you with a way to reach these elements directly by pointing the identifiers instead of the whole path to the element.

You can try something like:

`//input[@name='login']
//input[@name='password']`

More info at: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

oh i see, i re try with the element and i noticed that the one i wanted was showing as hidden using firebug so i just try the next one up and the web driver could locate the item, it was a simple app to send an email the prompt that i wanted to locate was the 'TO' field. and thanks guys for giving me the correct way of using the Xpath property